# Prevent string being printed python

Tags: python, io, output, stdout

I'm using some library and I can't edit its source.  There is a function in the library that I have to call, and when I call it, it makes this file that I want; however, at the same time, it prints this warning to the screen hundreds of times.  The warning is always the same.

> Warning during export : no corresponding GDSII layer found for process
>    and purpose

This is kind of annoying and makes me printing anything to stdout/stderr useless, because it just gets flooded with this silly warning.

I know how to redirect stdout/stderr by simply assigning them a different file.  Is it possible to simply check what will be written to stdout/stderr, discard it if it's that string, otherwise, print it?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't edit the library?

Comment: Did you try [-W](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W) flag?

Comment: Yes, it's not my library, and it's running from the owners server.  It's also in the process of being commericialised.

Comment: I recommend letting the owners know that their library has some extraneous `print` statements/calls, and no one likes a chatty library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use something like...

**3.x**

```
import sys
from _io import TextIOWrapper

class StdoutFilter(TextIOWrapper):

    def __init__(self, stdout):
        super().__init__(stdout)
        self.stdout = stdout

    def write(self, output):
        if output != "don't write this":
            self.stdout.write(output)

sys.stdout = StdoutFilter(sys.stdout)

print("hello, world!")
print("don't write this")

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

**2.x**

```
from StringIO import StringIO

class StdoutFilter(StringIO):

    def __init__(self, stdout):
        StringIO.__init__(self, stdout)
        self.stdout = stdout
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for that, certainly does help!  There seems to be an odd problem getting it to work for python 2.7.  I get the error: `attribute error: readable` at `super().__init__(stdout)`.  Any ideas why?  A Google search didn't seem to reveal much.

Comment: @Jean-Luc You're welcome. See the update for the 2.x version!